# No TestFlight crash reports

Tags: testflight

I just want to get confirmation that Crash reports are NOT available from TestFlight users.

Can anyone confirm that they are able to receive iOS crash reports for beta apps distributed via TestFlight.

Here is an extract from the Apple developer library about the Crashes Organiser:

```
How Crash Logs Are Collected and Aggregated into Crash Reports
Apple provides a service that collects crash logs from users and organizes them into downloadable crash reports. However, crash logs are collected only if you upload an app with the symbols. (In the Archives organizer, select the “Include app symbols for your application…” box when you upload your app to iTunes Connect.) For apps released in store, the user must also agree to share crash logs with developers. TestFlight users automatically share crash logs with developers. The service that creates the crash reports does the following:
Collects crash logs from apps and app extensions running on user devices
Symbolicates the crash logs (replaces memory addresses with human-readable names)
Compares stack traces to identify and group similar crash logs into crash reports
Removes all personal user data from crash logs
Provides the total number of unique devices where the crash occurred
Provides a sample set of crash logs for each crash report
Updates crash reports daily
```

And here is an extract from iTunes Connect:

```
Can I get crash reports for my builds?
No. Crash reports for prerelease builds are not provided.
```

So I am confused about whether crash reports are available via iTunes Connect for apps in beta with TestFlight !

Answer (score 0):

In XCode's Organizer you will have the crashes for all your builds https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg4O4.png but directly in iTunes Connect (which is not that useful anymore) you will only have stats for the released builds

Nicolas